# Refactor matrix permutations in numpy's style

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, vectorization

I wrote the following code to do multiplication of matrix permutations and I was wondering if it can be written in a `numpy` style, such that I can get rid of the two for loops:

```
Z = np.empty([new_d, X.shape[1]])
Z = np.ndarray(shape=(new_d, X.shape[1]))
Z = np.concatenate((X, X**2))
res = []
for i in range(0, d):
    for j in range(i+1, d):
        res.append(np.array(X.T[:,i]* X.T[:,j]))

Z = np.concatenate((Z, res))
```

while: `X shape is (7, 1000), d = 7, new_d=35`

any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1**

We could use [`np.triu_indices`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html) to get those pair-wise permutation-indices and then simply perform elementwise multiplicatons of row-indexed arrays -

```
r,c = np.triu_indices(d,1)
res = X[r]*X[c]
```

**Approach #2**

For memory efficiency and hence performance especially on large arrays, we are better off slicing the input array and run a single loop with each iteration working on chunks of data, like so -

```
n = d-1
idx = np.concatenate(( [0], np.arange(n,0,-1).cumsum() ))
start, stop = idx[:-1], idx[1:]
L = n*(n+1)//2
res_out = np.empty((L,X.shape[1]), dtype=X.dtype)
for i,(s0,s1) in enumerate(zip(start,stop)):
    res_out[s0:s1] = X[i] * X[i+1:]
```

To get `Z` directly and thus avoid all those concatenations, we could modify the earlier posted approach, like so -

```
n = d-1
N = len(X)
idx = 2*N + np.concatenate(( [0], np.arange(n,0,-1).cumsum() ))
start, stop = idx[:-1], idx[1:]
L = n*(n+1)//2
Z_out = np.empty((2*N + L,X.shape[1]), dtype=X.dtype)
Z_out[:N] = X
Z_out[N:2*N] = X**2
for i,(s0,s1) in enumerate(zip(start,stop)):
    Z_out[s0:s1] = X[i] * X[i+1:]
```

Comment: Your first approach is so smart !! Whenever I write too much code in python (Matrices), I know it can be written in a shorter way but because I'm still beginner I'm not aware of all of those functions. Many thanks :))